# RxJava 2 / Retrofit 2 - NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I need to perform a request, if my token is expired I need to refresh it and retry the request.

This is how I'm trying to do it, at the moment I can refresh the token but it throws me a NetworkOnMainThreadException. It finishes the request,update the token and reaches logs, but that exception its killing me. How can I avoid that?

```
    public Observable<Estabelecimento> listarEstabelecimentos() {
    return Observable.defer(this::getListarEstabelecimentoObservable)
            .retryWhen(throwableObservable -> throwableObservable.flatMap(
                    throwable -> {
                        if (throwable instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
                            return mRequestManager.getTokenObservable(AutoAtendimentoApplication.getContext())
                                    .doOnNext(response -> /* log stuff */)
                                    .flatMap((Function<AuthResponse, ObservableSource<?>>) response2 ->
                                            getListarEstabelecimentoObservable()
                                                    .doOnNext(estabelecimento ->
                                                            /* log stuff */)
                                                    )
                                    );
                        }
                        return Observable.error(throwable);
                    }));
}
```

NetWorkErrorHandler:

```
    public <T> T  processError(Response<T> response ) {
    switch (response.code()) {
        case 401:
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        default:
            return response.body();
    }
}
```

Token:

```
       private Observable<AuthResponse> getToken(Context context,
                                          @GrantType.GrantTypeDef String grantType, @Nullable String refreshToken) {

    SessionManager sessionManager = SessionManager.getInstance(context);
    Usuario usuario = sessionManager.getUser();

    AuthRequest request = new AuthRequest(usuario.getUsername(),
            usuario.getPassword(), grantType, refreshToken);

    return mAuthAPIService.getToken(request)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(response -> storeTokens(response, context));
}
```

Edit 1: I'm pretty sure the problem happens inside the flatmap and put subscribeOn does not solve the problem

Edit 2: Code update

Comment: i am guessing this line, mRequestManager.getTokenObservable(AtendimentoApplication.getContext())
                                    .doOnNext(response -> Log.i("NEXT", "OK")).doOnError(throwable1 -> Log.i("ONERROR", "NOT OK")); causes the error?

Comment: post your implementation of mRequestManager.getTokenObservable

Comment: this line, estabelecimento.getIdSincronizacao() makes the request?

Comment: mLoginViewModel.listEstabelecimentos() this is the request. The line that you showed its me parsing the data

Comment: provide some more code!

Comment: Thats it! Any other call that you see its just retrofit

Comment: this might be a longshot, but is `estabelecimento.getIdSincronizacao()` by any chance a network request?

Comment: The problem happens when I try to refresh the token from this piece of code:                     (Function<Throwable, ObservableSource<?>>) throwable -> {
                        if (throwable instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
                            return mRequestManager.getTokenObservable(AutoAtendimentoApplication.getContext()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                    .doOnNext(response -> Log.i("NEXT", "OK")).doOnError(throwable1 -> Log.i("ONERROR", "NOT OK"));
                        }

Comment: Try to remove **all** your `subscribeOn/observeOn` calls, except the one that is located above the final `subscribe`.

Comment: @MaximOstrovidov, I tryied that still getting the same exception

Comment: Please provide a minimum example to reproduce your problem, so others could run your code. There are chances that during that process you'll figure out what's the problem by yourself :)

Comment: Ok, I did updated the answer with everything that i'm doing

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your network is running on main thread, you can solve it by adding `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` and `subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())` to your observable.

The `observeOn(...)` means that the results are emmited on the specified thread - in this case the UI thread.

The `subscribeOn(...)` call is basically where the request is processed. If omitted the computation is done on current thread.

Comment: Where do you think that I should put it? Already done at the subscriber

Comment: basically everywhere you make a network request, the `observeOn(...)` is not needed if you don't need the result to be on UI thread.

Comment: Added where I do perform the subscribe to the question

Comment: I think you will need to add it to `getTokenObservable` as well

Comment: I gone crazy here and add it basically anywhere... but still got the same error here. I'll update my answer with i'm currently doing

Comment: which line actually throws the exception?

Comment: the throwable inside the flatmap

Comment: this will not solve, already being done this path, i with always trigger network and main thread, just create a new thread within the observable and start it with the request. otherwise a bunch of refactoring will need to be undertaken!

Comment: the `Schedulers.io()` does just that without the need to create unneeded Thread objects.

Answer (score 1):

Alright let me try and explain this in plain English. When you use `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()`, it wraps the current block in the main thread, its no different from any method in your activity. The main context does not allow execution of networks requests, hence why yours fail. To remedy this your flow of observable need to change to accommodate the execution.

To test this theory, change all `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` to `Schedulers.io()` , therefore you would of to comment out all call to ui processing , like toast messages and leave behind simple Log messages , try it and see what happens.

you need to refactor this section, because it calls on the main thread.

```
 if (throwable instanceof UnauthorizedException) {
                            return mRequestManager.getTokenObservable(AutoAtendimentoApplication.getContext()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                                    .doOnNext(response -> Log.i("NEXT", "OK")).doOnError(throwable1 -> Log.i("ONERROR", "NOT OK"));
```

Here is a theoretical solution, do not wrap the getToken in a observable, create a class where the getToken can be called independently , let it return an observable from which you can then subscribe and observe from. thats all really, currently you wrap the above in the main thread.I do not know how else to make this simpler
                            }

Comment: Changing all `AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()` to `Schedulers.io()` does not fix the problem, still getting network on main thread exception.

Answer (score 1):

the problem must be on your getToken. You do not need the observeOn and the subscribeOn:

```
    return mAuthAPIService.getToken(request)
        .map(response -> storeTokens(response, context));
```

Adding those lines genererate the error. I do think the only place you need to specify its in the final subscriber.